# Add URL field to wordpress taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

Like the title states I'm trying to add a URL field to taxamony.

```
function create_post_type() {  
register_post_type( 'brands',  
    array(  
        'labels' => array(  
            'name' => __( 'Brands' ),  
            'singular_name' => __( 'Brands' )  
        ),  
    'public' => true,  
    'menu_position' => 5,  
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'brands')  
    )  
);  
} 

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' ); 

function partner_taxonomy() {  
   register_taxonomy(  
    'partners',  
    'brands',  
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'label' => 'Partners',  
        'query_var' => true,  
        'show_ui' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'partners')  
    )  
);  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'partner_taxonomy' );
```

From here how do I add an URL field to "Partners" taxonomy? Also code to be added to the taxonomy.php page for display.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never done it through direct coding. I use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for this.

Any type of custom field can be shown there, text, image, checbox, etc.
And you have to set the location rule to be the Taxonomy screen.

[image: acf taxonomy rule]

Category screen with custom fields:

> [image: custom fields in category]

*[Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/tutorials/retrieving-values-from-other-pages-taxonomy-user-media/) on how to retrieve the data.*